# c calls function writen in assembly language

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly

I am practicing C and assembly language mix programming using GCC. And this error occered:

```
1 deng@ubuntu:~/workspace/leos_test$ make
2 ld -o deng c.o asm.o
3 ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008048074
4 c.o: In function `main':
5 c_and_asm.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `add'
6 c_and_asm.c:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `printf'
7 make: *** [deng] Error 1
```

This is the C code:

```
1 #include<stdio.h>
2 void extern add(int * i);
3 void main(){
4    int i=1;
5    add(&i);
6    printf("%d ",i);
7}
```

Here is the assembly language code:

```
1 .globl _add
2 _add:
3 push %bp;
4 mov %sp,%bp;
5 mov 0x4(%bp),%eax;
6 incw (%eax);
7 popw %bp;
8 ret
```

This is the makefile:

```
1 deng: c.o asm.o
    2 ld -o deng c.o asm.o
3 c.o:
    4 gcc -o c.o -c c_and_asm.c
5 asm.o:
    6 as -o asm.o c_asm.asm
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your c_asm.asm file to this:

```
.section .text
.global add
.type add,@function
add:
push %bp;
mov %sp,%bp;
mov 0x4(%bp),%eax;
incw (%eax);
popw %bp;
ret
```

include in your ld this parameter `-lc` and better change the file extension to `.s`

Comment: Why have we got so much 16-bit code in the asm file? I'd use `%esp`, `%ebp`, `incl`, and `popl`! I'd lose the `-c` switch and give gcc the asm.o file and let it invoke ld for ya. If you invoke ld yourself, besides the `-lc`, you may need `-I/lib/ld-linux.so.2`, and `-melf_i386` if you're on a 64-bit system (`-m32` for gcc). If you get a mysterious "file not found" error when you run your masterpiece, try that `-I` switch...

Comment: This is a copy paste from the question body. Let it be lil challenge for him. He will learn more ...

Comment: Fair enough. Forget what I said, Deng. :)

Comment: Yeah! Deng but if you still need help ... we are here! :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `_` from `_add` and fix `.globl` to `global`:

```
segment .text
global add

add:
```

Comment: with GNU `as` the syntax is very different ... there is no any `segment` keyword and all keywords need a dot before ... `.align` `.global` ...